# How to get ACF values when creating a new post in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, post, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to get the ACF custom fields values right after creating a new post.

I have this function, which works PERFECTLY fine when using the old Wordpress editor, but does not work when using the new REST API, as everything is sent by AJAX. The $_POST variable is empty in that case.

Can someone help me figuring out how to retrieve the custom fields values of a new post ?

```
add_action('transition_post_status', 'my_custom_function', 10, 3);
function my_custom_function($new_status, $old_status, $post) {
if($post->post_type === 'post') :
    if('publish' === $new_status && 'publish' !== $old_status) :

        $acf = $_POST['acf'];
        create_mailchimp_campaign( $post, $acf );
    endif;
endif;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using WorPress Classic Editor plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/)?

Comment: yes I did, I used it to develop and debug my function. But I need to leave the new ajax editor, but cannot make my code work with it